Is a linear map bounded if you can pull out a series?
Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and $A: X \rightarrow Y$ a linear mapping. I was wondering whether the following equivalence holds $$ A \quad \text{bounded} \Leftrightarrow A\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty Aa_n, \enspace \forall (a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subset X: \sum_n a_n \enspace \land \enspace \sum_n Aa_n \enspace \text{converges}.$$ The direction $\Rightarrow$ is known to be trivially valid. I don't believe so strongly in the reverse direction and if it is valid, it would have to be shown with a clever series. Unfortunately, I didn't get any further despite a few considerations. Does anyone have any tips?

$<\infty$ doesn't mean much in a Banach space, because the space is not ordered. Just say "if $\sum a_i$ converges."

@ThomasAndrews Oops, you're right of course. I've improved it.

This follows from the closed graph theorem. To prove $A$ is bounded, it suffices to show that, if $b_n \to b$ in $X$ and $Ab_n$ converges to some $y$, then $y = Ab$. Let $a_0 = b_0$ and $a_n = b_n - b_{n - 1}$ for $n \geq 1$. Then $\sum_n a_n$ converges to $b$ and $\sum_n Aa_n$ converges to $y$. So the condition you wrote down indeed implies $y = Ab$.

Thanks for the answer. I'm just wondering, as you already said, you have to show it for any converging sequences $b_n$. Now $b_n$ could converge in $X$ but $\sum_n b_n$ could not.

You could take $X = \mathbb{R}$, $b_n = 1$. Clearly $b_n \rightarrow 1$, but $\sum_n b_n = \infty$

@Victor That's exactly what I'm saying. Can you explain your thoughts in more detail DavidGao.

@Noctis I’m not saying $\sum_n b_n$ converges. I’m saying $\sum_n a_n$ converges, where $a_n = b_n - b_{n - 1}$ (except $a_0 = b_0$) so the sum is a telescoping series, i.e., the partial sum $\sum_{n=0}^N b_n$ is simply $b_N$, so $b_N \to b$ implies $\sum_n a_n = b$. Similarly for $\sum_n Aa_n$.

@DavidGao Oh that's right. That was stupid of me, thank you very much :)
